# Displaying javaScript value in VF page

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

I want to display the value from the javaScript in the VF page it self. Please tell me how it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good related post on the subject [VisualForce Component Ids & Javascript](http://th3silverlining.com/2009/06/17/visualforce-component-ids-javascript/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

The Visualforce Page:

```salesforce
<apex:outputText id="myPlaceholder" value=""/>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var myString = 'Hello';
    jQuery('[id$=myPlaceholder]').text(myString)    
</script>
```